# Why does Collections.swap assign the target list to a variable of a raw type?

Tags: java

In the source for JDK 1.6, the Collections class' swap method is written like this:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

What reason is there for creating a final copy of the passed list? Why don't they simply modify the passed list directly? In this case, you also get the raw type warning.

Comment: Here's the related source on Grepcode for anyone interested: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.swap%28java.util.List%2Cint%2Cint%29

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no copy of the list, there is only a copy of the reference to the list. The final keyword is not important. However, it is important that a raw type is used. If the parameter would be used instead, the compiler would report an error:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    // ERROR: The method set(int, capture#3-of ?) in the type List<capture#3-of ?>
    // is not applicable for the arguments (int, capture#4-of ?)
    list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
}
```

This means, that they are using the intermediate variable to circumvent the shortcomings of generics, and to get rid of the error message.

The interesting question is: Why don't they use a generic method? The following code works:

```
public static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
}
```

The answer is, that this method produces warnings in old code invoking the method with raw types:

```
List list = ...;
// WARNING: Type safety: Unchecked invocation swap2(List, int, int)
// of the generic method swap2(List<T>, int, int) of type Swap
Collections.swap(list, 0, 1);
```

Comment: So they use the final reference to the list to avoid using generics?

Comment: Indeed, they are using the intermediate variable to circumvent the shortcomings of generics, and to get rid of the error message.

Comment: The API shouldn't be polluted with the implementation detail of a method with a generic parameter where a wildcard would suffice (and be cleaner and easier to understand, assuming a basic knowledge of Java). Now, you could use the generic method as a implementation method and have the public method call that (a common idiom), however, I suspect the extra bytecode may occasionally trip up HotSpot inlining (or someone was concerned about that even if it doesn't).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, the reference being final has nothing to do with it. It's just generally good practice to have final vars and in some cases helps the JIT compiler to make more efficient code.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I wonder if you still agree with your comment all these years later? The fact `swap` needs to read from and **write to** the list is not something I would consider an implementation detail in this case. That's pretty much the contract. With that in mind, they really _should_ have used `List<T>`, because `List<?>` implies "this list won't be written to".

Comment: @Slaw `List<?>` does not imply read-only. Without going further than the `Collections` class, there's `reverse`, `rotate`, `shuffle`. Or a `List<?>` itself you can call `clear` `remove` (both), `removeAll`, `retainAll`, and those methods on a `subList`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Yes, you're right. It's not read-only, but it isn't fully writable either. You cannot add or "set" an element when you have a `List<?>`. And a swap method that _takes a list_ absolutely implies "setting" elements. I suppose my philosophy here is that if you have to suppress a compiler warning then you're doing it wrong, unless there's literally no way to avoid the warning. In this case, there is a way: Make the method generic (where the type argument is determined by the list itself). I'm not sure I understand how that pollutes the API.

Comment: @Slaw Oh there absolutely is a way to do it whilst keeping the public interface, and it is standard. You forward to a private method that captures the wildcard. `public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) { swapImp(list, i, j); } private static <T> void swapImpl(List<T> list, int i, int j) { list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i))); }`.

OTOH, IIRC, there is a case in NIO where a wildcard could be used but isn't.