# Why no warning in java.util.Collections.swap(List<?>, int, int)?

Tags: java, generics

I know a similar question has been asked and answered at [Why does Collections.swap copy the input list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788259/java-jdk-1-6-implementation-details/10788405#10788405) but what I'm asking is somewhat different :

ConsiderJDK1.7 source for java.util.Collections.swap()

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

Clearly List l alias has been declared because you can't write into List list, anyway I can't understand why there's no warning issued for using a rawtype (List l), and for performing set() in such an unchecked fashion.

What's even more strange to me is that if I blindly copy that method in any of my own classes, than I do get warnings (as I expected) obliging to annotate with @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })

I see no @SuppressWarnings annotation on Collections class as a whole [only on some methods - not on swap()] so I have no explanation for this behavior.

Am I missing something basilar ?

[I'm using Eclipse Kepler]

Comment: What makes you think there's no warning? Have you compiled the Collections class?

Comment: No, I hadn't compile Collections class, but now that I did I can see that swap() DOES issue the warning I expected.

My fault : I simply thought Sun programmers put every effort in making API compile without any warning (that could be suppressed via @SuppressWarnings annotation); that doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Its just a source code and probably missed out including the @SuppressWarnings.
In reality,if you are using Java compiler 1.5 or above,you would get such warnings

Answer (score 0):

There is no assignment of a raw type to a parameterized type; so no @SW rawtypes.

There is no casting of the wild card; so no @SW unchecked.

Comment: No, I have to confute what you say, if I compile the Collections class on its own swap() DOES need @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" }) to be completely warning free.